# Why doesn't awk print any value?

Tags: awk

I am beginning to learn `awk` and came across something that when I run the following commands

```bsh
$ echo ":a:b:c:" | awk '$1=$1' FS=":" OFS="$"
$ echo "a:b:c:" | awk '$1=$1' FS=":" OFS="$"
a$b$c$
```

First command returns nothing, but I expected it to return `$a$b$c$`, similar to the second command. And in general, it never prints anything when the field separator is at the beginning of the line. Why so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `awk` script, printing is triggered as the default action, which in turn depends on "side-effect" evaluation of assignment `$1=$1` as a pattern.

In the first case, there is an empty field before the first separator, so `$1` is the empty string, which evaluates FALSE. In the second case, `$1` is the non-empty string `a`, which evaluates TRUE, triggering the default print action.

Comment: So how does `{$1=$1}1` makes it work?

Comment: A correction: `{$1=$1}1` is two *pattern-action pairs*: the first is `{$1=$1}` where the default pattern is `1`, so it will evaluate on every line; the second is `1` where the default action is `{print}`.

Answer (score 5):

You're relying on the truth value of the first field to make awk print the record. The truth value of an empty string is false, so awk doesn't do anything other than the assignment. Print explicitly (or using some other always true condition, like `1`), instead of using the first field as the check:

```
echo ":a:b:c:" | awk '{$1=$1; print}' FS=":" OFS="$"
```

Comment: So how does `{$1=$1}1` makes it work?

Comment: `1` is an always-true condition, like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't let the result of an action evaluate to be a condition unless you have a very specific need (e.g. you try to remove a char if present and want to do something if that succeeds).
2. Code is more readable when you see variables being set before you see the code that uses them so don't list variable assignments in the file list **after** the
   script unless you have a very specific need (e.g. changing values
   between files), list them up front using `-v` or `BEGIN` or an
   assignment before the call to awk that you can access from
   `ENVIRON[]` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001).
3. Use single quotes around all strings (including scripts) in shell
   unless you have a very specific need to use double quotes or no
   quotes (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

So your script should be `awk -F':' -v OFS='$' '{$1=$1}1'`.